# Hugo - output only changed files

Tags: hugo

when I add a new post or change an existing post in my **content** directory, Hugo rebuilds the entire *content* directory. Is it possible to write out *only* the modified files? I can't find any switch that seems like it would do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Static site generators generally rewrite everything. Hugo has no incremental builds AFAIK. Jekyll (another popular SSG) does, but Jekyll is about 10 times slower than Hugo. I think incremental builds are only interesting when you have a huge amount of pages. How large is your website?

Comment: It is not about the size. I use `git` to track changes in my website. If I add or edit a single page, my commit message gets applied to every page because the entire website is regenerated. Seems it would not be very difficult to implement incremental builds – regenerate the entire site *only* if anything in the layouts changes. Else, generate *only* the changed content

Comment: Git is meant to track the source, not the generated output. I think you are using git wrong.

Comment: well, wrong is in the eye of the beholder. I am serving my website from Github and I consider the website itself to be the source of the, well, the website. I have to do the git add, commit, push dance anyway for the generated HTML files. May as well track the changes…

Comment: You are right... but for the correct commit message you can look at the 'origin' repo, right? You can use git the way you like it, but it may not be very convenient this way. However, you were asking for an incremental build option. I do not think that exists.